# Selecting in DataFrame without typing 'INDEX', but by calling user-defined variable as existing index/value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, geopandas

I'm looking for a way to select a specific part of a DataFrame. This works as follows:

```
df = gpd.read("path_to_file")

df.set_index(['OBJECTID'], inplace=True)

Polygon = df.loc[['81207'], 'geometry']
```

(the code continues with other operations using the same 'OBJECTID' in different GeoDataFrame; this is needed to not lose geometry of points and/or polygons as only one geometry type can be linked to a GeoDataFrame)

This gives the correct output. However, the same process will be incorporated in a function to receive similar output for a user-defined input of the 'OBJECTID'. I'm therefore looking for a way to select data based on a user-defined variable: `OBJECTID = 81207`. How can an index be called by using a variable?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Example of what I would like to achieve:

```
def Building(OBJECTID):
    OBJECTID = OBJECTID
    print("Building with OBJECTID:", OBJECTID)
    Polygon = df.loc['OBJECTID'] #OBJECTID defined in function
    Points = df2.loc['OBJECTID'] #OBJECTID defined in function
    return (Polygon, Points)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

This can be done by formatting the variable as a string.

```py
def Building(OBJECTID):
    print("Building with ObjectID:", OBJECTID)
    Polygon = df.loc['{}'.format(OBJECTID)]
    Points = df2.loc['{}'.format(OBJECTID)]
    return Polygon, Points
```

Hope this is helpful for others.

Comment: you don't need to format anything. Passing the object ID directly will work, e.g., `Polygon = df.loc[OBJECTID]`